# how to check if url is valid on iphone

Tags: iphone

i am downloading a file from URL,but how to check whether URL is working or not??

```
NSString *durl = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://xyz/ServicesVersion.aspx"];


 durl = [durl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];




NSURL *urla = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:durl]autorelease];
```

**but lets say durl is dead ( i mean some garbage value then how to check that)??**
// UPDATES

what i meant was how to do URL error handling so that i can switch to my local file if url is showing some error ??

Comment: Your code indicates a lack of understanding about pointer-based memory management.  Please read http://boredzo.org/pointers/ on what a pointer is and what it means for your code.

Comment: In prajakta's defense, he's really only missing an autorelease. If the question weren't tagged "iphone" I'd suggest that he might be using garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is complete garbage, then `NSURL` won't be able to be initialized by it, and will return `nil`.

Comment: is there way to catch header value like 200 , so that i can make a check point

Comment: When you use NSURLConnection you can check the NSURLResponse.  See the documentation for the respective classes.